# Prestashop checkout process not loading if I create an account

Tags: prestashop

​I have a problem in checkout page when I am finishing an order, if the user wants to create an account and I fill the field "password" and after that I click continue to go to the payment gateway the page stays loading and loading without show errors...

If I do the same without create an account it works properly.

I attach video to show the problem better:
https://www.loom.com/share/69c332ca340444c2b0bb037cb24ef59b

Sometimes I get this error:

```
    UnexpectedValueException
RecursiveDirectoryIterator::__construct(/home/customer/www/ignasic13.sg-host.com/public_html/src/PrestaShopBundle/Controller/Admin/Sell/Catalog/Product): failed to open dir: Too many open files

in GlobResource.php line 112
at RecursiveDirectoryIterator->__construct('/home/customer/www/ignasic13.sg-host.com/public_html/src/PrestaShopBundle/Controller/Admin/Sell/Catalog/Product', 4608)
at RecursiveDirectoryIterator->getChildren()
at RecursiveCallbackFilterIterator->getChildren()
at iterator_to_array(object(RecursiveIteratorIterator))
in GlobResource.php line 112
at GlobResource->getIterator()
in GlobResource.php line 153
at GlobResource->computeHash()
in GlobResource.php line 67
at GlobResource->isFresh(1645538544)
in SelfCheckingResourceChecker.php line 34
at SelfCheckingResourceChecker->isFresh(object(GlobResource), 1645538544)
in ResourceCheckerConfigCache.php line 99
at ResourceCheckerConfigCache->isFresh()
in ConfigCache.php line 60
at ConfigCache->isFresh()
in Kernel.php line 584
at Kernel->initializeContainer()
in Kernel.php line 135
at Kernel->boot()
in Kernel.php line 195
at Kernel->handle(object(Request), 1, false)
in index.php line 82
```

Answer (score 0):

in my case it was old Mailchimp modules. Check what modules are hooked to hooks with "customers" in name and try to disable it.

Best regards,
sfp

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).